# wp_get_attachment_link filter custom class

Tags: wordpress, media

I've searched a bunch online, found a few snippets that all point towards the same filter 'wp_get_attachment_link' but for some reason it's not working.

Maybe a bug in the WP Core?
It should be simple.. Just get the url markup and append a fixed class.

```
function add_custom_class( $link ) {

    global $post;

    return str_replace( '<a href', '<a class="test" href', $link );

}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'add_custom_class' );
```

**Edit:**
This works!

```
function my_custom_imglink_class( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' ) {

    $classes = 'image-popup';

    if ( preg_match( '/<a.*? class=".*?">/', $html ) ) {

        $html = preg_replace( '/(<a.*? class=".*?)(".*?>)/', '$1 ' . $classes . '$2', $html );

    }
    else {

        $html = preg_replace( '/(<a.*?)>/', '$1 class="' . $classes . '" >', $html );

    }
    return $html;

}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'my_custom_imglink_class', 10, 8 );
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of `$link`? Does the filter actually get run at all? Some themes implement their own way of getting attachments, just check that the `add_custom_class()` function is actually being called and check the value of `$link` is what you expect.

Comment: What I mean is, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code, so either it's not being triggered, or the `str_replace` is failing.

Comment: It's crazy here.. looks like the wp_get_attachment_link function is totally ignored by WordPress while adding an image to a post via the Media uploader. You know the Advanced image settings section, there you can add a custom class-name to the url ( not img tag ) - I'm trying to do that by default, so the author doesn't have to do this every time he/she ads an image-url to the post.

Comment: Try the `image_send_to_editor` filter. I'm pretty sure it triggers for all content and not just images. I'll do a little digging if that doesn't work.

Comment: This could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042890/add-class-to-wordpress-image-a-anchor-elements